# Django form.is_valid returns false when a FileField is set to required

Tags: python, django, forms

So I'm trying to make a form in Django with a FileField. 
My forms.py looks like this:

```
from django import forms

class WordcloudForm(forms.Form):
    matrix = forms.FileField(required=True)
    min = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    max = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    # mask = forms.FileField(required=False)
```

I want the FileField to be a required field.
views.py:

```
def form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WordcloudForm(request.POST)
        print(form.is_valid)
        if form.is_valid():
            if 'matrix' in request.FILES:
                uploaded_matrix = request.FILES['matrix']
                print(uploaded_matrix.name, uploaded_matrix.size)
        min = form.cleaned_data['min']
        max = form.cleaned_data['max']
        print('min',min,'max',max)
        print(form.errors)
```

When `forms.FileField(required = True)` in forms.py, form.is_valid() returns false:
[image: required=True]

When `forms.FileField(required=False)` in forms.py, form.is_valid() returns true: 
[image: required=False]

When I submit the form with `forms.FileField(required = True)` my `print(form.errors)` states: "This field is required" even though I do add a file.

I tried different file formats to make sure the problem didn't just occur with the image I was using for testing.
What am I missing?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please add your code and output as text to the question. Not as an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) you need to pass `request.FILES` along with `request.POST` when initiating form instance:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = WordCloudForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        # rest of the code
```

Also please rename your view method from `form` to anything meaningful, because you have a variable named `form` inside the method. Same with naming of variables `min` and `max`, they conflict with python's `min` and `max` functions. Your IDE is already marking them.